# Compare Items in two Lists and return non matching Items

Tags: c#, list

So I have two Lists.

```
List<Farmer> CSVFarmer;
List<Farmer> Farmers;
```

CSVFarmer List gets its items from a method that will read a csv file.

Farmers List gets its items from a table in a sql database;

Now what I want to do is compare the two lists and return a list of non matching items;

For example if List CSVFarmer has:

```
FarmerName     ContractNumber   ContactNumber
John           2468             12345
Mike           13579            15790
```

And List Farmers has:

```
FarmerName     ContractNumber   ContactNumber
Mike           13579            15790
```

The list being returned should only have one item in it : Farmer John.
Farmer Class:

```
 public class Farmer:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int _id;
    string _firstName;
    string _farmerNo;
    string _contactNumber;

    public Farmer()
    {
        _firstName = string.Empty;
        _farmerNo = string.Empty;
        _contactNumber = string.Empty;
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }
    public string FarmerNo
    {
        get { return _farmerNo; }
        set
        {
            _farmerNo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FarmerNo");
        }
    }
    public string ContactNumber
    {
        get { return _contactNumber; }
        set
        {
            _contactNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ContactNumber");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged (string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

}
```

Ive tried this:

```
public class vmUserManagement
{
public List<Farmer> Farmer { get; set; }
public List<Farmer> CSVFarmers { get; set; }
public List<Farmer> Farmers { get; set; }


public vmUserManagement()
    {
        CSVFarmers = new List<Farmer>();
        Farmers = new List<Farmer>();
        Farmer = new List<Farmer>();
   }

public List<Farmer> getAllFarmers()
    {
        Farmers = RepoDapper.getAllFarmers();
        return Farmers;
    }

public List<Farmer> CSVImportFarmer()
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFile.DefaultExt = ".csv";
        openFile.Filter = "(.csv) | *.csv";

        var browseFile = openFile.ShowDialog();
        if (browseFile == true)
        {
            string FilePath = openFile.FileName;
            List<Farmer> values = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath).Select(v => FromFarmerCsv(v)).ToList();
            CSVFarmers = values;
        }
        return CSVFarmers;
    }

 public static Farmer FromFarmerCsv(string csvLine)
    {
        string[] values = csvLine.Split(',');
        Farmer farmer = new Farmer();
        farmer.FirstName = values[0];
        farmer.FarmerNo = values[1];
        farmer.ContactNumber = values[2];
        return farmer;
    }


public List<Farmer> validateFarmerList()
    {


        foreach (var a in CSVFarmers)
        {
            foreach (var b in Farmers)
            {

                    if (a != b)
                    {
                        Farmer.Add(a);
                    }

            }
        }

        return Farmer;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that  I will end up with two entries in List Farmer. Both for Farmer John and Farmer Mike. When I should only be getting a List containing Farmer John. Why is that?

I've also tried using Except:

```
 public List<Farmer> validateFarmerList()
    {           

        Farmer = CSVFarmers.Except(Farmers).ToList();
        return Farmer;
    }
```

But I still get two items in my Farmer List (Farmer John and Mike) instead of one.
Am I missing something? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: So non-matching doesn't mean that some properties are different? I ask because also Mike  has a different contract number. Only the `FarmerName` is relevant? What if two farmers have the same name? Identity by name is not reliable.

Comment: `Farmer` class would be helpful, could you provide it? in general `Equals` and `==`, `!=` operators

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter Sorry but the Farmer Mike is suppose to have the same contract Number and contact number in both lists, I've edited the post. Identity will be done by contract Number.

Comment: @gaa added the farmer class

Comment: ok so you have solution in answer of @TimSchmelter

Comment: @Tyron: so you mean that not the name of the farmer is relevant to identify him but the `ContractNumber`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter that is correct, contact number will be used to identify a farmer, as the contract number will be unique to every farmer.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Tyron: for the sake of completeness i have added two other approaches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have't overridden `Equals` and `GethashCode` in your `Farmer` class. That's why `(a != b)` doesn't work and also `Enumerable.Except` fails for the same reason: only **references are compared** and both are different instances.

How should .NET know that the `ContractNumber` of the farmer is relevant to identify him? One wayy is to tell it by overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`:

```
public class Farmer : IEquatable<Farmer>
{
    public string FarmerName { get; set; }
    public string ContractNumber { get; set; }

    // .... other properties etc

    public bool Equals(Farmer other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return string.Equals(ContractNumber, other.ContractNumber);
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Farmer) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (ContractNumber != null ? ContractNumber.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```

Now you can use `Except`:

```
Farmer = CSVFarmers.Except(Farmers).ToList();
```

---

2nd way is to implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<Farmer>`, f.e if you can't change the `Farmer` class itself or you don't want to change it's behaviour and just want a custom comparer:

```
public class FarmerContractComparer : IEqualityComparer<Farmer>
{
    public bool Equals(Farmer x, Farmer y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, x) || ReferenceEquals(null, y)) return false;
        return x.ContractNumber == y.ContractNumber;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(Farmer obj)
    {
        return (obj.ContractNumber != null ? obj.ContractNumber.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}public class FarmerContractComparer : IEqualityComparer<Farmer>
{
    public bool Equals(Farmer x, Farmer y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, x) || ReferenceEquals(null, y)) return false;
        return x.ContractNumber == y.ContractNumber;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(Farmer obj)
    {
        return (obj.ContractNumber != null ? obj.ContractNumber.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```

You can use this comparer in many LINQ methods, for example also in `Enumerable.Except`:

```
Farmer = CSVFarmers.Except(Farmers, new FarmerContractComparer()).ToList();
```

This approach has the advantage that you could provide different comparers for different tasks.

---

3rd approach:  use LINQ and don't create a new class(less reusable and efficient but less work):

```
Farmer = CSVFarmers.Where(f => !Farmers.Any(f2 => f.ContractNumber == f2.ContractNumber)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either create a class implementing `IEqualityComparer<Farmer>` and pass an instance of that as a second parameter to `.Except()` **or** implement `IEquatable<Farmer>` on your Farmer class.

The other answer already has a good implementation of the latter. If you *always* want farmers to be equal when their contract number is equal, use that one.

So if you want your Except work on contract numbers, but in other places you want other criteria, you need the first option:

```
class FarmerEqualWhenContractEqualComparer : IEqualityComparer<Farmer>
{
    public bool Equals(Farmer x, Farmer y)
    {
        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        //Check whether the farmers' contracts are equal.
        return x.ContractNumber == y.ContractNumber;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.
    public int GetHashCode(Farmer farmer)
    {
        //Check whether the object is null
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(product, null)) return 0;

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
        return farmer.ContractNumber?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var changedOrNew = CSVFarmers.Except(Farmers, new FarmerEqualWhenContractEqualComparer()).ToList();
```